# Space between heading 'Contents' and the first line in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage[compact,tiny]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0.00in}{0.48in}{5mm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\normalsize\filcenter}{%
  \centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\normalsize\uppercase}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\normalsize\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}

\tableofcontents

\univchapter[first chapter]{first chapter}
some text
\univchapter[second chapter]{second chapter}
some more text
\end{document}
```

The definition of `\univchapter` is

```
\newcommand\univchapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@univchapter\@schapter}

\def\@univchapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\chaptername\, \protect\numberline{\thechapter} \uppercase{#1}}%
                    \else
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chaptername\, \uppercase{#1}}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

The error it generates while creating a MWE and also while executing the code with your suggestion is `Use of \@ doesnt match its definition. \univchapter...i\thispagestyle{plain}global \@t             opnum\z@afterindentfal....`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package and change the length `\cftaftertoctitleskip`; a little example (instead of `0pt`, you can use the length that best suits your needs):

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{first chapter}
some text
\chapter{second chapter}
some more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

To be consistent, you might also want to change `\cftafterlottitleskip` (for the LoT) and `\cftafterloftitleskip` (for the LoF).

Since the `titles` option for `tocloft` is being used (as it is now clear from an edit to the original question), changes to `\cftaftertoctitleskip` will have no effect; in this case, a possible solution would be to patch the `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, and `\listoftables` commands to add some negative space; here's an example with the new settings provided in the edits to the original question:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[compact,tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}{\vskip-10pt\@starttoc{toc}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@starttoc{lof}}{\vskip-10pt\@starttoc{lof}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\@starttoc{lot}}{\vskip-10pt\@starttoc{lot}}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand\univchapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@univchapter\@schapter}

\def\@univchapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\chaptername\, \protect\numberline{\thechapter} \uppercase{#1}}%
                    \else
                    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chaptername\, \uppercase{#1}}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0.00in}{0.48in}{5mm}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\normalsize\filcenter}{%
  \centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\normalsize\uppercase}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\normalsize\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\univchapter[first chapter]{first chapter}
some text
\univchapter[second chapter]{second chapter}
some more text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used your suggestion, now I have edited the question, I need to use it under certain circumstances, please help me

Comment: @ArunDesiraju nevermind. I updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: If I use your updated solution, it works for the MWE, but for my thesis, it gives an error while inputting the acknowledgments, and chapter names. I have updated the MWE with the format for the chapter title. Please check it out

Comment: @ArunDesiraju my last update uses exactly the settings you posted and there's no error. If you are getting an error, the cause has to be somewhere else. Please add (I mean add and not change) a minimal, complete version of the problematic code (reproducing the problem mentioned) to your question.

Comment: I am looking for the problem in my thesis, but the solution that you provided moves the heading up or down by the parameter specified against \vskip. But I want the distance between the top edge of the page and the heading to be unchanged, and move the contents below the heading up or down. How can it be done?

Comment: @ArunDesiraju No; my solution doesn't move the heading. If this is the case in your code, then something else is going on and without the actual code (or a minimal version of it), little or almost nothing can be done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6279/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-arun-desiraju)

Comment: @ GonzaloMedina I am not able to login. I dont know what is the problem. You are right. The heading doesnt change position. I am not using \chapter, but using \univchapter, who's definition I am putting in the question. I am not able to generate a MWE, and I dont understand what the error is. I am relatively new to Latex.

Comment: @ArunDesiraju try loging-out from this site; then log in again to the site and try to login to the chat room following the link from above.

Comment: No, still not able to login to chat

Comment: @ArunDesiraju can you login to the main chat room? http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ArunDesiraju the solution is really easy: I am updating my answer right now.

Comment: @ArunDesiraju answer updated; all you had to do was to enclose the definition of `\univchapter` and `\@univchapter` inside `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Please, let me know of this solves your problem.

Comment: this works for ToC. How should I modify for list of figures and list of tables.

Comment: @ArunDesiraju please see my updated answer.